# Using Lenovo P52's built-in infrared cameras to take photos or video in the infrared spectrum?

Tags: windows-10, video, photos, ubuntu-18.04, infrared

I have a Lenovo P52 that came with IR cameras in order to use Windows Hello. I was wondering if it is possible to use these cameras to take photos or video in the infrared spectrum.

I did some searches online but could not find anything about it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to use the IR cameras for such purposes?

I dual-boot on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, so I am open for solutions in either of the two OS's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on my Linux Mint machine, the infrared camera appears

- as an option for video conferencing applications, such as Microsoft Teams and Google Meet
- as an option for [Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/) imaging program
- as an option for [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) imaging program

For some reason, the picture I see in Cheese is even stranger than the one in the other apps :)